# Custom UITableViewCell Data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` that has a switch in it, and have the switch event wired to the table cell so I can capture the event.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class SwitchTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var cellSwitch: UISwitch!

    @IBAction func switchValueChanged(sender: UISwitch) {
        print("Switch changed")
        print("**")
        print(self.title.text!)
        print(self.cellSwitch.on)
        print("**")

    }
}
```

I get the correct title text and boolean value for the switch.

Now, when the switch event fires I need to call a method in my `ViewController` referencing the cell that gets fired.  I would like to have a method in my controller (ViewController.swift) that I can call when the table cell switch toggles like this:

```
func tableCellChange(titleText: String, state: Boolean){
  // Do something with the object represented by titleText
}
```

A bonus would be if I could have a `DoorEntity` member in the table cell and skip looking up the entity from the name

```
func tableCellChange(doorEntity: DoorEntity, state: Boolean){
  // Do something with the DoorEntity
}
```

This would involve my table cell looking like this (note the added DoorEntity field)

```
import UIKit

class SwitchTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var cellSwitch: UISwitch!
    var doorEntity: DoorEntity!
    @IBAction func switchValueChanged(sender: UISwitch) {
        print("Switch changed")
        print("**")
        print(self.title.text!)
        print(self.cellSwitch.on)
        print("**")

    }
}
```

Here's how the switch gets added via my table model.  I cannot figure out how to pass the `DoorEntity` to the Switch class here:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("GarageDoorCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SwitchTableCell
        let door = self.doorEntityList[indexPath.row] as! DoorEntity
        cell.textLabel?.text = door.name
        print("Cell switch")
        if(cell.cellSwitch == nil){
            print("Null switch")
        } else {
            print(cell.cellSwitch)
        }
        if(door.name == "Mike"){
            cell.cellSwitch?.on = false
        } else {
            cell.cellSwitch?.on = true;
        }
        return cell
    }
```

I guess I could have a `setDoorEntity` on the custom table cell, but it seems like there should be a better way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This all sounds reasonable. What's your question? What's stopping you from storing a reference to the `DoorEntity` in the cell? You don't always want your views to have direct dependencies on your model classes since that reduces reusability, etc., but sometimes it's just the best solution. If you want to really do things right you could define some interface that the cell knows about and which `DoorEntity` can implement, thereby eliminating the direct dependency.

Comment: I guess I was asking if it was reasonable, so thanks.  I think what I am going to do is create a door service object that has nothing to do with UI stuff.  The table cell will get a reference to the service and the door service will send the commands to the web service I have.  Right now the view is calling a REST service to get a list of doors, so the service will do that as well to de-couple things.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a delegate method?

```
protocol MainViewCellDelegate
{
    func tableCellChange(doorEntity: DoorEntity, state: Boolean)
}
```

In your table cell class:

```
import UIKit

class SwitchTableCell: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var cellSwitch: UISwitch!
    var doorEntity: DoorEntity!

    var delegate: MainViewCellDelegate? = nil

    @IBAction func switchValueChanged(sender: UISwitch)
    {
        if (delegate != nil)
        {
            delegate!.tableCellChange(doorEntity, state: cellSwitch.on)
        }
    }
}
```

In your view controller:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("GarageDoorCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SwitchTableCell
    let door = self.doorEntityList[indexPath.row] as! DoorEntity
    cell.textLabel?.text = door.name
    cell.delegate = self
    print("Cell switch")
    if(cell.cellSwitch == nil)
    {
        print("Null switch")
    }
    else
    {
        print(cell.cellSwitch)
    }
    if(door.name == "Mike")
    {
        cell.cellSwitch?.on = false
    }
    else
    {
        cell.cellSwitch?.on = true;
    }
    return cell
}

func tableCellChange(doorEntity: DoorEntity, state: Boolean)
{
    // Do something with the DoorEntity
}
```

Don't forget to add the delegate class MainViewCellDelegate to your controller class.

Maybe this helps?

Greg